# Debugging cordova application on device and localhost webpack

Tags: android, cordova, webpack-dev-server, device-driver, taco

I have a following setup:

- Run cordova app from Visual Studio 2017 (on device connected via USB)
- Cordova app loads app js files from localhost (webpack dev server)

This function pretty well on simulator (apart from the fact that I have to restart simulator after each change), but I cannot get it running on the real device. There are two problems:

1. Seems all the urls in cordova are messed up when I use `<base href="/"/>` (required for my angular 2 application). This I can do a hack fix by using direct file urls.
2. I cannot access localhost (and this is the most problematic)

I need to test some things like e.g. payment, that do not work on any emulator and wanted to debug it directly from localhost without building the application and publishing it each time.

Is it possible to do something about that so that I can debug store access from cordova on my device while service .js files from localhost?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2017, did you install the Tools for Apache Cordova (TACO)?  With those in place, you can run the app easily on a connected device (I wrote the docs for that product, so I tested this hundreds of times :-)). Regarding running on the simulator, you can also use Cordova Simulate in Visual Studio, and the app will automatically refresh the browser window after every change. No reason to restart the simulator ever. Cordova Simulate replaces the Ripple Emulator included in earlier versions of TACO.

I'm assuming you're trying to test on an Android device connected to the system? Don't forget, localhost points to the device running the application. Localhost on a mobile device points to the local device, NOT the system you're debugging from. To access the local PC from an Android device, you have to point to 10.0.2.2, a special address the android device opens up to connect to the host PC. You can read (a little) more about that here, on my blog: http://johnwargo.com/mobile-development/android-emulator-access-to-localhost.html.

Comment: When you link your blog, make sure that it's blatantly obvious that it's your blog. A few words, like my edit, is plenty; as long as anyone scanning your answer can tell that it's your content you're linking to, it's fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I do understand that localhost is different, that's why I asked, did not know about 10.0.2.2, will try to use it :) Regarding the simulator in browser, every time I do a change in my webpack controlled application, the simulator dies right away (Can't remember 100% error message now, can check it later). So the browser is indeed refreshed and the change is detected, but I get a failure instead of the app. Perhaps it is because I do reference another host (webpack) and not directly from the file system.

Comment: I don't know, but if you provide details (error messages and so on) you'll be able to get better help. You didn't answer my question: are you using TACO? If not, why not? Microsoft has some pretty amazing tools for Cordova development and it streamlines the whole process. You can configure WebPack as part of the VS build process, and even use it with Cordova Simulate.

Comment: Hi, was able to try the solution just now. 10.0.2.2 does not work unfortunately. net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. I am using TACO, yes. I am running the app on the device directly from Visual Studio 2017.